# Java Обработать непроверяемое исключение ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, массивы, исключения

Всем добрый день. Сразу оговорюсь-я учусь месяц на курсе Java, 34 года и перехожу с другой отрасли. Поэтому просьба сильно не пинать))
И так задание

1. Обработать непроверяемое исключение ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

- Создать класс ArrayExceptionTest
- Создать main метод
- Создать и проинициализировать произвольный массив из 5-6 элементов.
- Создать статический метод printArray(array, start, end), который выводит на экран элементы массива от индекса start до индекса end.
- Добавить обработку исключения ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, для операции получения элемента массива по индексу. При возникновении ошибки выводить на экран сообщение вид: «Ошибка. Попытка обращения к несуществующему индексу: текущий индекс = i; размер массива = s;»
- Вызвать несколько раз (с разными значениями) метод printArray в методе main для созданного ранее массива.

  ```
  public class ArrayExceptionTest {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          int[] testArray = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};    
      }  
  }
  ```

Затык произошел на моменте создания статического метода. Если я правильно понял необходимо создать метод с параметрами (Массив, Начало массива, конец массива) который будет выводить элементы массива по указанным параметрам
Поиск ничего не подсказал(понимаю что навык еще не отработан) нашел

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArray, startIndex, endIndex);
```

но данный вариант создает просто новый массив и если к endIndex добавить лишнее будет новый массив с нулями, но не старый массив при выходе за который можно было бы получить ошибку
Соответственно дальнейшее решение задание зависло. Помогите решить. Заранее спасибо кто ответит и ткнет где надо было что почитать

Comment: Создать статический метод printArray(array, start, end) ... зачем копировать массив??Arrays.copyOfRange... создай метод где в блоке try/catch пробегаешься по всем элементам массива

Comment: Так это задание такое нужно по пунктам выполнить его

Comment: а где в задании копировать массив??

Comment: Так я написал что единственное что нашел и оно было похожее это копирование массива

Comment: копировать массив не надо, он в метод передаётся .в методе написать блок try/catch, в нём в цикле пробежаться от  start, 
до end и когда ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException вывести "Ошибка и тд"

Comment: если не сложно покажите как это правильно в коде выполнить.

Comment: внизу страницы есть пункт чат, ищи комнату 0000

Comment: Не хватает репы))

Comment: на javarush зарегестрирован?

Comment: Да на этом ресурсе зареганый

Comment: ну ищи и пиши по нику стасевич

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
public class ArrayExceptionTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] testArray = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
            System.out.println("Корректный вывод:");
            printArray(testArray, 0, 6);
            System.out.println("С ошибкой:");
            printArray(testArray, 10, 15);
        }

        public static void printArray(int[] array, int start, int end) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка. Попытка обращения к несуществующему индексу: " +
                            "текущий индекс = " + i + "; размер массива = " + array.length + ";");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Здесь метод `printArray` выводит числа из массива от индекса `start` (включительно) до индекса `end` (не включительно). Это не уточняется в задании, но если хотите чтобы выводился элемент по индексу `end` измените в цикле условие `i < end` на `i <= end`.

Вывод программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо смотрю и ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо за совет

Comment: Спасибо да именно то!!! Сижу смотрю свои ошибки которые не понял и допустил!!

Comment: с вами можно как то пообщаться в личке? не чат) не хватает репутации

Comment: @paraplan, я сам недавно здесь, не знаю можно ли тут в личке общаться

Comment: если можно в телегу @GradientAspen )))